# Custom save method in Django

Tags: python, django

I have written a custom save method in my `Django model class link`.
I have added this method so that if i use admin panel to enter data it will get executed and i didn't have to enter data manually for that field but now when i enter data from admin panel it still asks me to enter the data but then it simply overrides my entry.Is Their any way it will not allow to enter that particular value from admin panel.

```
import uuid
import base64
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

def _generateShortUrl():
    """
        This function will generate base64 encoded id
    """
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes)[:6]


class link(models.Model):
    """
        This is a link class 
    """
    link = models.URLField()                                    # To store user entered URL
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)                       # How many hits for particular URL
    last_used = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)             # When URL is last used 
    short_url = models.CharField(max_length=6,unique=True)      # base64 URL encoded id  

    def linkValidate(self):
        timediff = datetime.datetime.now() - self.last_used                       
        return timediff.min

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Custom Save method for link model 
        """
        self.short_url = _generateShortUrl()        
        super(link, self).save(*args, **kwargs)   


class user_info(models.Model):
    """
        This is a user_info class 
    """
    user_agent = models.TextField()                 # Stores user_agent name used by user
    user_ip = models.ManyToManyField(link)          # Stores user's IP

    def userIP(self):
        """Method to return tags related to store"""
        return ','.join([t.link for t in self.link.all()])

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

class linkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
        link admin class
    """
    list_display = ('link','hits','short_url','last_used',
                    'linkValidate')
    ordering = ('hits',)

class userInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
        user_info admin class
    """
    list_display = ('user_agent','userIP')

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
admin.site.register(link,linkAdmin)
admin.site.register(user_info,userInfoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your Model & ModelAdmin not to require those fields.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude

Answer (score 1):

You can change you field definition to:

```
short_url = models.CharField(max_length=6,unique=True, default=_generateShortUrl)
```

or change you `linkAdmin` adding :

```
exclude = ('short_url',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try assigning a value to shortURL when the instance is created rather then when stored.